# How to let Debezium switch to next binlog automatically

Tags: mariadb, debezium, binlog

In my project, Debezium still pointing on the same binlog, he doesn't switch to the next binlog. I have always to restart the connector debezium so he can read from the current binlog.
How can I let debezium do this automatically please ?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%binlog%';`;

Comment: @SimoAnagda Found any solution?